# Remove unused GEOID in geo_join

Tags: r, leaflet, tigris

I am attempting to plot profitability on top of counties in Minnesota, Iowa, and Nebraska. Using `leaflet` and `tigris`, I have been able to plot ALL counties, whether or not I have data for it. This leaves me with a few counties with colors and the rest labeled as NA. Is there a way for me to remove all NA's from my `geo_join` data so that it just isn't used ala unused Wisconsin areas? I have tried using `fortify`, but I can't figure out how to determine what county boundaries I'm looking at when I merge the TIGER boundary lines with my County FIPS file in order to remove them.

Here is what my `leaflet` currently looks like: [image]

My code to get the map is this:

```
library(tigris)
library(leaflet)

pal <- colorNumeric(c("yellow","dark red"),county$Construction.Cost,na.color="white")
IA_counties <- counties(state="IA", cb=TRUE, resolution ="20m")
MN_counties <- counties(state="MN",cb=TRUE,resolution="20m")
NE_counties <- counties(state="NE",cb=TRUE,resolution="20m")
IA_merged <- geo_join(IA_counties,county,"GEOID", "GEOID")
MN_merged <- geo_join(MN_counties,county,"GEOID","GEOID")
NE_merged <- geo_join(NE_counties,county,"GEOID","GEOID")
popupIA <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(IA_merged$Construction.Cost, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
popupMN <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(MN_merged$Construction.Cost, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
popupNE <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(NE_merged$Construction.Cost, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))


leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("MapQuestOpen.OSM") %>%
      addLegend(pal = pal, 
                values = IA_merged$Construction.Cost, 
                position = "bottomright", 
                title = "County Projects",
                labFormat=labelFormat(prefix="$")) %>%
      addCircles(lng=yup2$lon, lat=yup2$lat,weight=.75,fillOpacity=0.01,color="red",
                 radius = 96560) %>%
      addCircles(lng=yup2$lon, lat=yup2$lat,weight=.75,fillOpacity=0.01,color="blue",
                 radius = 193121) %>%
      addPolygons(data = IA_counties, 
                  fillColor = ~pal(IA_merged$Construction.Cost), 
                  layerId=1,
                  fillOpacity = .25, 
                  weight = 0.05, 
                  popup = popupIA)%>%
      addPolygons(data=MN_counties,
                  fillColor=~pal(MN_merged$Construction.Cost),
                  fillOpacity=0.25,
                  weight=0.05, 
                  popup = popupMN) %>%
      addPolygons(data=NE_counties,
                  fillColor=~pal(NE_merged$Construction.Cost),
                  fillOpacity=0.25,
                  weight=0.05, 
                  popup = popupNE)
```

I apologize for not including reproducible data, but if needed, please ask. I'm hoping that this is more of a simple `na.color=` formula solution. The map looks "okay" as of now, but I'd like it if it's possible to not have to make the `fillOpacity` so light so the NA counties don't stand out.

Thanks for any and all help and please, let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, embarrassingly, the answer to this question was as simple as I had hoped. I tweaked the following `na.color` code and it worked exactly as I wanted.

```
pal <- colorNumeric(c("yellow","dark red"),county$Construction.Cost,na.color="transparent")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm the creator of the `tigris` package.  Thanks so much for using it!  In the development version of `tigris` on GitHub (https://github.com/walkerke/tigris), I've added an option to `geo_join` to accommodate inner joins, which would remove the unmatched data entirely from the resultant spatial data frame (if this is what you are looking for).  You can also supply a common merge column name as a named argument to the new `by` parameter if you want.  For example:

```
IA_merged <- geo_join(IA_counties, county, by = "GEOID", how = "inner")
```

should work.  I'm still testing but I'll probably submit this update to CRAN in January.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Just want to say that I really appreciate your `tigris` package and its usefulness with `leaflet`. Keep up the great work!